# CodeIgniter UPDATE query not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with a CodeIgniter `UPDATE` query.

My model:

```
function update_order($id,$old_order){

    //Update The order
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM cat WHERE `cat_order`='$old_order' ");
    $row =  $query->row();

    $this->db->query("UPDATE cat SET cat_order='".$row->cat_order."' WHERE id='".$id."' ");
    $this->db->query("UPDATE cat SET cat_order='$old_order' WHERE id ='".$row->id."' ");

}
```

The `SELECT` query is working 100% but the two `UPDATE` queries are not.

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? Can you elaborate that please?

Comment: You could also do the update in one query, use `print_r($row)` to see the structure of what is returned from the query. Also you may have a pos SQL injection on `$old_order`

Comment: Did you print out your update statements and run manually to check if the statement itself works?

Comment: @مبرمج السلطنة: It has been already said, but I repeat: Be careful of SQL injection. If you publish this, you will be hacked very, very soon. Take care!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's see what's happening (at least, what I can understand);

1. You select everything from table `cat` where `cat_order` is equal to, say, 2 (`$old_older`);
2. Of all the records returned, you only take ONE row (`$row = $query->row()`);
3. You update the only row returned, i.e. the first in your recordset, setting it's new value to the same value extracted by the previous select, (`$row->cat_order`), using an ID I don't know where it comes from and to what row is referring;
4. You update the only row returned by the **first select**, identified by its ID (`$row->id`), giving its `$old_older` value (`SET cat_order='$old_order'`), in this case 2.

I mean, your queries are fine, but you're updating with the same value, that's why you don't see changes.
Or am I overlooking something obvious?

By the way, you've injection holes; either use the Active Record or use query bindings with placeholders:

```
$sql = "UPDATE table SET column = ? WHERE id = ?";
$this->db->query($sql, array($value, $id));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update it with Active Record. It sanitizes data for you. No worries about SQL Injection.

```
$this->db->where('id',$id); 
$this->db->set('cat_order',$row->cat_order);
$this->db->update('cat');
```

Do the same for second update query.

Comment: thanks all but all the solution not working with me i dont know w7y Is this not possible programmatically ؟

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the id's are primary keys, and must have no quotes:

```
$this->db->query(
  "UPDATE cat SET cat_order='".$row->cat_order."' WHERE id = " .$id );

$this->db->query(
  "UPDATE cat SET cat_order='$old_order' WHERE id = " . $row->id );
```

Comment: And cat_order field, is that a varchar or a int?

Comment: Mr. Kemal Fadillah  i mean i can print_r($row) and it showing all the data but Update query not working .

Comment: Thanks all i foud the problem with Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Check if the column you are trying to update exists in the database structure.